# HTML5 application for smarthphone(android, ios) with localStorage date()

Tags: html, datetime, date, local-storage

FOR THE MODERATORS!!
I CREATED THIS QUESTION ON stackapps AFTER A RESEARCH INTO THE STACK SECTIONS.
DO I NEED TO DELETE THIS ONE?

Hi I'm creating a simple HTML5 app which uses a timeout().
The basic function of the APP is:
you select an Item and a timeout() starts. It works properly but if I close the application the timer will stop of course.
I'm trying to store it in localStorage but it does not work for what I need.

here is my code

get current date

```
var current = new Date();
```

check if localStorage is empty or not. If not, it calculate the difference in milliseconds beetwen the stored date and the current date.

```
function update() {
  if (localStorage.time != undefined){
  var diff = current - localStorage.time;
   alert (diff)
}

update();
```

here the function save for the date to be stored and it check the difference beetwen the two dates.

```
function save() {
  localStorage.time = new Date();
  click_time = localStorage.time;
  var diff =  click_time - current;
   alert (diff);
   }
```

clear the localStorage

```
   function clear() {
   localStorage.clear();
   }

$(document).ready(function() {
$('input#save').click(function(){
  save();
});
$('input#clear').click(function(){
  clear();
});
});


<input type="submit" value="click me!" id="save"/>
<input type="submit" value="clear" id="clear"/>
```

But I just get NaN!!The problem is how do i need to store the date in the localStorage and how can i get it as a date?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all `new Date();` with `new Date().getTime();`

The differences between new Date().getTime()'s will be in milliseconds.

And just to elaborate:

Using new Date() will return a string like this "Fri Mar 30 2012 12:02:33 GMT-0400 (EDT)." So when you try to perform subtraction between two of these strings, you get NaN.

new Date().getTime() will return an integer like this 1333123359919. This is in milliseconds from January 1st, 1970 (or something like that). So the difference between two of these will give you the number of milliseconds between the two calls, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks you!! it works. I can not give you a vote up because of my low reputation.

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I could help! Also, if you ever need to turn those long integers back into a string, you can make another Date object like this `new Date(1333123359919)` where 1333123359919 is the value saved from getTime().

Comment: But the strange thing is that if the date is not in the localStorage it works properly. That's why I was a bit confused and I focused on the localStorage function instead of the date.

Comment: Oh right! When you create a generic `new Date()` it is a Date object and treated as a string most of the time...but apparently you can in fact subtract two of these and end up with the right answer. When you write to localStorage it becomes a real string, with none of the other properties that the Date object used to have. So when you try to recover this from localStorage you end up with just a string. Remember...in localStorage *everything* is a string.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm building my first simple app which include localStorage and a client-side database and this part is important because it should handle a timer. When the user click on save, a timer starts so, if they close the app and they open it again, the app will calculate the differences of time and will check the difference beetwen this and the timer so it will restart the timer from the milliseconds left. I don't know if it's clear what I said due my English.